# Is there flood map prediction tutorial available to use with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, references, flood

I just want to ask if anyone knows a direct tutorial for flood mapping prediction.
The scenario that my supervisor asked me is this:
If we pour water on a specific location, where will it flow and how much is the runoff to cause a flood?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using? Do you have access to its Spatial Analyst extension?  Please use the edit button to expand upon your question with these details which I believe will be important for any potential answerer to know.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

http://www.quantdec.com/SYSEN597/studies/flood/index.htm

Also, GeoWEPP for erosion analysis and HEC-RAS for mitigation measure analysis